# php adding columns to a table

Tags: php, database

I've got the function:

```
<?php
function calculatepoints($position) {
    $points = array (25, 18, 15, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1);
    if ( $position > count($points) ) { return 0; }
    else { return $points[$position-1]; }
}
?>
```

and would like to add a points column to my table. I've tried using:

```
<td><?php echo $points; ?></td>
```

but kept getting the error: "Undefined variable: points in ..."

Could someone please let me know what it is that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: $points will only works inside your calculatepoits function.

try something like $points = calculatepoints($position);

Comment: At the moment $points is stuck in the function calculatepoints.  To access it you would need to add return $points to the bottom of that function, and then when calling it do something like $points = calculatepoints($position)

Answer (score 0):

It is because `$points` is in function's scope, yet you're trying to access it on global scope.

Do: `<?php echo calculatePoints($position) ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<?php echo calculatepoints($position); ?>
```

You should read up on [PHP variable scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I kept getting the errors " Undefined variable: position" and "Undefined offset: -1"

Comment: @aab In which case, you're not defining your `$position` variable that you're inputting into the function.

Comment: How could I do that please? As I'm trying to write a parameter of position, and return the number of points that position is worth. (e.g. if we pass it: an integer “1”, it should return an integer “25”).

Comment: @aab do you understand how to set [variables in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)?

Comment: @aab you should read the article I linked in my previous comment. You must first understand the basics before attempting to jump ahead to concepts like the one you are struggling with at the moment.